# How can I configure a Swing JFrame to close on Cmd-W?

Tags: macos, swing

On OS X, users expect to be able to press Cmd-W to close a window.

Can I configure a JFrame to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, keybindings for the top-level windows are handled exclusively by the underlying OS. So on a Mac they should be already there, on a different system there is no meta key (? not sure, though, maybe has some simulation).

Anyway, you can add whatever additional keybinding you like to the JFrame's rootPane:

```
private void addMacCloseBinding(JFrame frame) {
    frame.getRootPane().getActionMap().put("close-window", new CloseAction(frame));
    frame.getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT)
        .put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control W"), "close-window");
    frame.getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT)
        .put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("meta W"), "close-window");
}

public class CloseAction extends AbstractAction {

    private Window window;
    public CloseAction(Window window) {
        this.window = window;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (window == null) return;
        window.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(
                window, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks - I had to remove the `WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT` constraint to get it to work in my particular case (a JFrame with a JFreeChart ChartPanel as its only child) but otherwise, that did exactly the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to specify the menu shortcut like this:

```
menuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 
                        ActionEvent.META_MASK));
```